# Vector of smart pointers destructor call

Tags: c++, c++11, smart-pointers

Why does the Node destructor get called only once instead of 5 times in the code below?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <memory>

struct Node {
    ~Node() {std::cout << "Node destructor called.\n";}
};

void foo() {
    std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Node>> nodes(5, std::make_shared<Node>());
}

int main() {
    foo();
    std::cout << "foo() ended.\n";
}
```

Comment: @prestokeys: It seems that you were somehow expecting the code to act like a *macro* that textually duplicates the argument expression into each element constructor. But that's not the case; the expression is evaluated *once* and bound to the constructor parameter. I guess that's the difference between expression evaluation and macros, and that's why it's still nice to have macros. Languages like Scheme let you do that properly.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Your vector contains five copies of the original shared pointer, all sharing ownership of the *one single pointee*.

To create five separate objects, each owned by one shared pointer, write it like this:

```
std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Node>> nodes;
for (int i = 0; i != 5; ++i) nodes.push_back(std::make_shared<Node>());
```

Answer (score 1):

[Kerrek SB](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34274325/2069064) explained the situation well, but to do what you want to do in a different way, you could also the [`std::generate_n`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/generate_n) algorithm:

```
std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Node>> nodes;
std::generate_n(
    std::back_inserter(nodes),
    5,
    std::make_shared<Node>);
```

This is more along the lines of what you thought you were doing originally.

Or, similarly:

```
std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Node>> nodes(5);
std::generate(nodes.begin(), nodes.end(), std::make_shared<Node>);
```